# Question marks in string, Although I'm using `utf-8` as a charset

Tags: php, wordpress, html, character-encoding

I'm using WordPress, In the **header.php** inside `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
```

Which returns:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Then in **index.php**, I have the following:

```
<h2>Veiðileyfi</h2>
```

That's an Icelandic word, It's shown on the homepage as:

```
<h2>Vei�0�8ileyfi</h2>
```

Why that's happening and how to solve that?

I searched about that, But most of them was about data from the DB and dealing with mysql, mysqli, PDO .. etc

Comment: could you clarify what you are asking here? Were you looking for having the character show up correctly, or trying to have it load a different charset which will allow you to type all the different icelandic letters without using hex codes?

Comment: I want to show the strings correctly with UTF-8 charset

Answer (score -1):

It's a special letter and so the browser isn't showing it correct. Use the hexcode

```
<h2>Vei&#240;ileyfi</h2>
```

Comment: also, here's the [link](http://graphemica.com/ð) with the hex code along with all the other information.